# Do humans breathe 21600 times in a day according to Yoga sastra?

Tags: yoga, reference-request

I came to know that a human breathes 21,600 times per day according to Yoga sastra.

Which shloka explicitly states it?

Comment: Yes... per minute 15 per hour 900... per day 21600..  that's why you see Kalasa of Nataraj temple is 21600 tall with 9 entry  points.  Through Pranayama if you reduce your breathing your life span extends

Comment: Is it for only humans or all living beings.?because the animals like tortoise lives hundreds of years which means their breathing rate is low?

Comment: @SomaSekhar, and animals like dogs which breathe very fast live only upto 20

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Hamsa Upanishad](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/hansa.html?lang=sa), Yoga Upanishad which belongs to Shukla Yajurveda, mentions that.

> अथ हंस ऋषिः । 
>  अव्यक्ता गायत्री छन्दः । 
>  परमहंसो देवता । 
>  अहमिति बीजम् ।
>   स इति शक्तिः । सोऽहमिति कीलकम् । 
>  षट् सङ्ख्यया 
>   **अहोरात्रयोरेकविंशतिसहस्राणि षट् शतान्यधिकानि भवन्ति** ।

[English Translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/tmu/tmu27.htm) by K. Narayanasvami Aiyar:

> (Here the performance of Ajapā Gāyaṭrī is given).
>
> "Now Hamsa is the ṛshi; the metre is Avyakṭā Gāyaṭrī; Paramahamsa is
>   the ḍevaṭā (or presiding deity) 'Ham' is the bīja; 'Sa' is the śakṭī;
>   So’ham is the kīlaka.  Thus there are six. **There are 21, 600 Hamsas
>   (or breaths)  in a day and night**.

Answer (score 10):

This is mentioned in Yogic texts as well as in numerous Tantras.

For example the [Vigyana Bhairava Tantra](https://www.indiadivine.org/content/files/file/198-vigyan-bhairav-tantra-with-english-translation-pdf/) says:

> The breath is exhaled with the sound 'Ha' and inhaled again with the
>   sound 'Sa'. Thus the individual always repeats this particular mantra
>   Hamsa. (155)
>
> This japa of the Devi which was previously indicated, (being repeated)
>   twenty-one thousand six hundred times during the day and night, is
>   easily available and difficult only for the ignorant. (156)

I am quoting from p 68 of the PDF.

[image]

Yet another reference for the same from [Dhyana Bindu Upanishad](http://www.astrojyoti.com/dhyanabinduupanishad.htm) linked with the Krishna Yajur Veda:

> 61(b)-63. The Jiva comes out with the letter ‘Ha’ and gets in again
>   with the letter ‘Sa’. Thus Jiva always utters the Mantra ‘Hamsa’,
>   ‘Hamsa’. The Jiva always utters the
>
> Mantra twenty-one thousand and six hundred times in one day and night.
>   This is called Ajapa Gayatri and is ever the bestower of Nirvana to
>   the Yogins.
>
> 64-66(a). Through its very thought, man is freed from sins. Neither in
>   the past nor in the future is there a science equal to this, a Japa
>   equal to this or a meritorious action equal to this. Parameshvari
>   (viz., Kundalini Sakti) sleeps shutting with her mouth that door which
>   leads to the decayless Brahma-hole

A related and interesting article which you can read is: [Time and the Kalachakra.](http://www.shivashakti.com/jyot2.htm)

Comment: Hamsa Upanishad also mentions same Ajapa Gayatri.

Comment: Yes saw and upvoted ur answer .. actually numerous Tantras talk about it too .. that article I linked is interesting u can read it...@TheDestroyer

Answer (score 7):

Apart from various Tantra as mentioned in other answers, [Garuda Purana, Chapter 15](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/gpu/gpu17.htm) also says that there are twenty-one thousand six hundred breaths in one day.

> 77-80. **It is said by the wise that the subtle movements of the breath in one day and night number twenty-one thousand six hundred**.
>
> It goes out with the sound of "ha," and enters again with the sound of "sa." The individual is, indeed, always repeating the mantra. "Haṁsa, haṁsa,"--
>
> Six hundred for Gaṇeśa; six thousand for Vedhas; six thousand for Hari; six thousand for Hara.
>
> A thousand for the Jīvātman; a thousand for Guru; a thousand or the Chidātman;--thus one should understand the respective numbers of the repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

Not only Humans even gods, and others also breaths 21,600 times a day but in their own calculation.

Shiva Purana 2.1.10.:

> 21-22. In the case of **all living beings,** Brahmā, Viṣṇu, Harā, Gandharvas, serpents, Rākṣasas, etc., **twenty one thousand six hundred respirations constitute the period of one day and one night,** O foremost among Devas.
>
> 23-24. Six respirations constitute the period of time one Pala. Sixty such Palas constitute one Ghaṭī. Sixty Ghaṭīs constitute one day and one night. (6 x 60 x 60 = 21600). There is no limit to the number of respirations of Sadāśiva. Hence He is undecaying.

And, interestingly these 21600 breaths of a whole day if converted mathematically it becomes 24 hours in modern terms. See below.:

- **Note.: s = seconds, b = breaths, p = palas, g = ghatis, m = minutes, h = hours, d = day.**
- Pala (पल).— Unit of time equivalent to 24 seconds.
- So, 1b = 24s ÷ 6b = 4s.
- Nos. of seconds in a day as per as scriptures = 4s × 6b × 60p × 60g = 86,400s.
- Nos. of seconds in 24 hours = 60s × 60m × 24h = 86,400s.
- Therefore, 21,600b = 24h = 1d.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an additional verse from Agni Purana.

**Ajapa Japa**

> Since Siva who resides in the bosom of all beings, himself recites the
> “Han”, “Sa” mantras (sounds spontaneously produced in the heart of a
> man at the time of respiration) even without the knowledge of that
> particular individual, hence persons who are cognizant of extra
> corporal principles, give the epithet of japa (recitation of a mantra)
> to that particular sound. These sounds are produced twenty-one
> thousand six hundred times in the course of a day and night. Thus, the
> lord of the yogis, seated in all human hearts, recites this
> spontaneous Gayatri mantra (Ajapa Gayatri) permeated with the essence
> of the (Hindu) Trinity and the man who can shut the door of his heart
> against the external world and merges his whole soul and identity in
> this recitation of the Ajapa, knows no second birth.

**Agni Purana 214.24-26**