# Do yoga scriptures mention the average number of human thoughts per day?

Tags: yoga, tantra, sandhyavandanam, mind, pranayama

There are several references to the [number of times a human breathes](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32065/do-humans-breathe-21600-times-in-a-day-according-to-yoga-sastra) in a day in general, which is typically around 21,600 times. The frequency of breath is an important factor in practices such as yoga and tantra.

Similarly, a great deal of attention is given to the concept of thoughts, or 'chitta vrittis,' in many yoga shastras. It is stated that one can reach higher states in yoga [if she is capable of consciously ceasing thoughts](https://patanjaliyogasutra.in/samadhipada1-2/).

It is widely recognized that there is a relationship between the frequency of breath and the frequency of thoughts. As a result, pranayama, the control of breath, is an essential stage in yoga.

In this context, I'm curious: is there any explicit mention in the scriptures of the number of thoughts a human being generally has in a day?

Comment: Thoughts are not countable.  Mental activity is continuous @hanugm

Comment: @SK If there is any reference for the same from scriptures. Please provide it as an answer.

Comment: I'll look for a scriptural reference.  But lyricist Shailendra, in the song "O Mere Sanam" in the 1964 movie Sangam illustrates closeness by saying "ek dil ke do armaan hain hum" - "we are like two desires of the same heart" @hanugm